# Comparing two lists in Mathematica

Tags: list, variables, math, wolfram-mathematica

i'm doing a program that given two lists and if part of one list is equivalent to the other entire list, then return the other part of the list. Difficult to explain, i'll leave the code here

```
E8[L_, P_] := Module[{},
  final = {};
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[L], i++,
   ok = True;
   For[j = 1, j <= Length[P], j++,
    If[L[[i, j]] != P[[j]], 
     ok = False
     ]
    ];
   If[ok == True, 
    coin = Take[L[[i]], {Length[P] + 1, Length[L[[i]]]}];
    AppendTo[final, coin]
    ]
   ];
  Return[final]
  ]

L = {{a, b, a}, {a, b, b}, {b, b, p}, {a, b, a, a}};
P = {a, b};
E8[L, P]
```

> Out={{a}, {b}, {p}, {a, a}

For some reason the program is evaluating as True the {b,b,p} and not assigning ok=False.
I need help with that. Thanks

Edit: I just need to find out why ok is not assigning False in that part of the code

```
If[L[[i, j]] != P[[j]], 
 ok = False
 ]
```

For sure the problem is there. I tried changing words {a,b} for numbers and the program is running properly, but when i try to compare words, it doesn't work. How could i compare lists with words?

Comment: Are you looking for the function `Complement` ?  If not, explain what you are trying to achieve.  You are almost certainly going about things the wrong way with your nested `For` loops; why it almost looks as if you are using Mathematic to write C !

Comment: Not familiar with Mathematica in particular, but I think, if I understand you correctly that, if you have sets A and B, you want the relative complement in B of the intersection of A and B, which simplifies to the relative complement of A in B. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29#Relative_complement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `UnsameQ` to test whether two expressions are not identical.

```
UnsameQ[L[[i, j]], P[[j]]]
```

or in the shorthand form

```
L[[i, j]] =!= P[[j]]
```

(This avoids changing the expressions being tested, as `ToString` does.)

In more *Mathematica* style your code could be written like this:-

```
e8[listL_, listP_] := Module[{plen = Length[listP]},
  DeleteCases[
   Map[If[SameQ[Take[#, plen], listP], Drop[#, plen]] &, listL],
   Null]]

listL = {{a, b, a}, {a, b, b}, {b, b, p}, {a, b, a, a}};
listP = {a, b};

e8[listL, listP]
```

> {{a}, {b}, {a, a}}

User-defined variable names generally start with a lower-case letter to avoid conflict with built-in functions and entities e.g. `I`, `N`, `C`, `O`, `D`, `E`.

Comment: Thanks for the UnsameQ function, i can cover all cases with that

Answer (score 1):

I changed the elements to strings and it seems to work:

```
  If[
    ToString[L[[i, j]]] != ToString[P[[j]]], 
    ok = False
    ];
```

but you can also just write

```
ok = ToString[L[[i, j]]] != ToString[P[[j]]]
```

since the result of the != operator is a boolean.